# Abelianization of a subgroup and its order

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H\subset G$ be finite groups, and $H^{ab}$ and $G^{ab}$ be their abelianizations (i.e. quotients by commutator subgroups). Is it true that $|H^{ab}|\leqslant |G^{ab}|$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be a non-abelian simple group and $H$ a non-identity abelian subgroup; what can you see?

Answer (score 2):

Take $$G = D_{2n}=\{a,b:a^2 = b^n = 1, \ aba^{-1} = b^{-1}\}$$ for any $n>4$, and let $H$ be the subgroup of degree $n$ generated by $b$.

Since $H$ is abelian, $H^{ab} = H$. However, the commutator subgroup of $G$ is $\langle b^2\rangle$, which is cyclic of order $\frac n2$ if $n$ is odd, and cyclic of order $n$ if $n$ is even.

Hence, $G^{ab}$ has order $2$ or $4$, which is certainly less than $|H|$.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not true.

Consider the group $G$ given by
$$G = \langle a,b \mid a^2 = b^2 = (ab)^5 = 1\rangle,$$
which is a finite group. The abelianisation $G^{ab}$ of this group is 
$$G^{ab} = \{1, a, b\} \cong \mathbb{Z}_3,$$
which has $3$ elements.

However, consider the subgroup $H \leq G$ given by
$$H = \langle ab \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_5,$$
which is abelian and hence equal to its own abelianisation: $H = H^{ab}$. This group has $5$ elements.